# Average of square of absolute value of inner product of two vectors of IID normal variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Consider two independently distributed sets of complex Gaussian random variables  $\{{X}_{i}\}^{N}_{i=1}$ and  $\{{Y}_{i}\}^{N}_{i=1}$ with mean zero and variances as $\sigma^{2}_{x}$ and $\sigma^{2}_{y}$ respectively. I have calculated the value as shown below. Can someone please help verifying it.

> $E[|\sum^{N}_{i=1}X^{*}_{i}Y_{i}|^{2}]$ =$ E[|\mathbf{X}^{\mathit{H}}\mathbf{Y}|^{2}]$=$N\sigma^{2}_{x}\sigma^{2}_{y}$

Comment: Please present some analysis in support. :)

Comment: Is $X^*_i$ the same thing as $\mathbf{X}_i$?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the typo

Comment: It looks like you are assuming that both sequences consist of iid random variables. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, $X$ and $Y$ are IID Gaussian random vectors so trying to find out average of square of absolute value of inner product of IID Gaussian random vectors

Comment: if $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian iid you should mention this in the question.

Comment: I have mentioned in the title, still edited.

Comment: Can someone tell the reason for downvote ?!

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:
$\begin{align*}
E[\sum^{N}_{i=1}|X^{*}_{i}Y_{i}|^{2}]  
    &= E[|\mathbf{X}^{H}\mathbf{Y}|^{2}]  
    =E[{(\mathbf{X}^{H}\mathbf{Y})(\mathbf{Y}^{H}\mathbf{X})}] \\ 
    &=E{[\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{X}^{H}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{H}\mathbf{X})]}  
    =E{[\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{H}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{H})]}  
    =\mathrm{tr}[E(\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{H}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{H})]  
    \\&=\mathrm{tr}[E(\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{H})E(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{H})]  
    \\&=\mathrm{tr}(\sigma^{2}_{y}\mathbf{I}_{N}\sigma^{2}_{x}\mathbf{I}_{N})  
    \\&=\sigma^{2}_{x}\sigma^{2}_{y}\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{I}_{N})  
    \\&=N\sigma^{2}_{x}\sigma^{2}_{y}
\end{align*}
$

Comment: @zhoraster, @ Therkel would you please check ?